# Googlespreadsheets update data format in a column

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I need to copy data from one google sheet to another programatically. In destination sheet the date format is dd-mmm-yyyy whereas is source sheet it is dd-mm-yyyy. What is the best way to retain the format in destination sheet while copying data?

Comment: Do you only want to copy the data containing dates or is there more data? It would be helpful if you could provide screenshots of the source and the destination spreadsheets

Comment: I have many data columns. In that 2 columns are on start and end date. Rest of the columns are plain text. Eg: Name, ID, First Name,Last Name, DateOfBirth, DateOfJoining....i need to copy all data with date to be formatted in dd-mmm-yyyy

Comment: See my solution below

Comment: Hi Zigan, thanks for your answer But I need to copy data from one google spreadsheet to another google spreadsheet preserving the date format of destination sheet. For this i need to either copy the format from destination to source before copying data, or i should format the date in source sheet and then copy the data to destination sheet.

Comment: If you copy between different spreadsheets rather than between sheets of the same spreadsheet, the procedure is a bit different. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to copy a data range from one sheet to another sheet of the same spreadsheet and you want to conserve the formatting:

You can use the method [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)) for ranges. The option `contentsOnly:true` will ensure that only contents will be copied, while the formatting of the destination sheet will be preserved.

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sheet1.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet2.getRange("A1"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

UPDATE

### If you want to copy a data range from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet  and you want to conserve the formatting:

You can use the methods [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). This will only copy the values and preserve the formatting of the destination sheet.

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2=ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range=sheet1.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
  sheet2.getRange(range).setValues(values);
  }
```